# 32bit COM dll (surrogate) doesn't load in 64bit Application (E_NOINTERFACE error)

Tags: c++, com, 64-bit

I have a COM object (C# .NET) which is registered and works fine when using it from a 32bit C++ application.

When using a 64bit C++ application it didn't work. I followed these steps ([click](http://www.gfi.com/blog/32bit-object-64bit-environment/)) to load the COM object in a 32bit process, however when calling CreateInstance (more exactly at the call to IUnknown->QueryInterface(...)) I get a E_NOINTERFACE error. (I see the DllHost.exe *32 in TaskManager)

Unfortunately this is not code I have written and I have absolutely no experience using COM objects. Could anyone point me in a direction how I could debug that or even what could be the problem with this?

I'm importing a type library in my code via

```
#import "BrowserClient.tlb"
```

and the call itself is:

```
hr = client.CreateInstance(__uuidof(BrowserClient::BrowserClient));
```

Edit: I don't know if this is useful, but the COM object is registered as InProcServer32. I use OLE/COM Object Viewer to look at it.

Comment: A 64-bit application can't use an in-process 32-bit COM object directly; you'll need to use an out-of-process COM object. It's possible to write a 32-bit out-of-process COM object that consumes the in-process COM object, and exposes an out-of-process interface for your 64-bit application to use.

Comment: I thought the Surrogate is there to match that problem. Doesn't the surrogate expose the originally inprocess interfaces as out-of-process interfaces to the aplication?

Comment: Yes, that's what the surrogate does.  However, it also needs to find a way to marshal the interface across the process boundary.  That requires entries in HKLM\Software\Classes\Interface for the 32-bit view and HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interface for the 64-bit view.  The E_NOINTERFACE you now get is for IMarshal.  But don't do this at all, the nice thing about .NET code is that it just as easily runs in 64-bit mode as well.  Just use the 64-bit version of Regasm.exe to register it.